# Read CSV file as text in AppleScript

Tags: csv, applescript

I want to read a CSV-file with contents like below:

```
123,456,789
```

#### AppleScript

I tired following:

```
set csvData to read "/Users/tim/Desktop/test.csv"
set csvEntries to paragraphs of csvData
repeat with i from 1 to count csvEntries
set num to (csvEntries's item i)'s text
log (num)
```

#### Problem

But this code outputs the `num` like this (all in one line):

```
"123,456,789"
```

Actually I want the `num` like:

```
"123"
"456"
"789"
```

Is the code `set num to (csvEntries's item i)'s text` wrong?

Comment: `to paragraphs` just splits the CSV-file contents into lines, so you will log one complete line. But you need to [split the line by the comma](https://erikslab.com/2007/08/31/applescript-how-to-split-a-string/). See [Working with text objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-253199)

Answer (score 1):

[Nigel Garvey's CSV-to-list converter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=125444#p125444) is the best I have seen.